# JavaScript / HTML highlighting / debugging in Eclipse using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, cordova, perspective

I am writing an app using PhoneGap for Android in Eclipse.  Since the project is an Android project, it's in a Java perspective.  For whatever reason, Eclipse won't highlight HTML and JavaScript for me while in an Android/Java project/perspective and switching to the JavaScript perspective doesn't highlight the code either.  Without highlighting or debugging tools, the debug process is very slow.

How do I tell Eclipse to highlight HTML and JavaScript for me while working in a Java Environment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you have JSDT(for JavaScript) and the Web Page Editor(for HTML) installed. From About Eclipse -> Installation Details, check for JavaScript Development Tools(JSDT) and Web Page Editor.

To install them :

- Install New Software -> Work with: Indigo (or Helios) ->Web, XML Java EE, and OSGi Enterprise Development -> JavaScript Development Tools
- Install New Software -> Work with: Indigo (or Helios) ->Web, XML Java EE, and OSGi Enterprise Development -> Web Page Editor

Alternatively, you could use the AppLaud Eclipse plugin I've created for doing PhoneGap development for Android. See the [Getting Started instructions](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start).

Comment: After installing, make sure to right click a file in the explorer and choose `Open with:` to select your newly installed editor. Don't do what I did, which was continue to open them in the default text editor view and then complain that the newly installed perspectives were not working!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer in my opinion, as this is a solution instead of a workaround

Answer (score 4):

The only real solution I found was to create a new html document and paste in the text from the original document, delete the original, then rename the new document.  This technique is dumb, but it works.

Comment: Weird, but it works, thanks! BTW, have you submitted a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is the best plugin for HTML and Javascript editing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This Eclipse plugin is useful:
http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2

Simon Mac Donald
http://hi.im/simonmacdonald